# repeat facet titles in a facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to repeat the facet title (e.g. for the columns during the entire plot)?

from https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html

```r
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))
```

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that 4, 5, 6 and 8 appears in the style of the facet title in each row. How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe use wrap? `facet_wrap(vars(drv, cyl))`

Comment: I would like to keep the row facet title on the right end, however the column title should appear in each of the three rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not aware of a default option but you could achieve your desired result using `patchwork`, i.e. make a separate plot for each row of your grid and glue them together:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

mpg |> 
  transform(cyl = factor(cyl)) |> 
  split(~drv) |> 
  purrr::imap(
    \(x, y) {
      # Remove axis title expect for the middle row
      remove_labs_y <- if (y != "f") labs(y = NULL)
      # Remove axis expect for the bottom row
      remove_axis_x <- if (y != "r") {
        theme(
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0, "pt")
        )
      }
      p <- ggplot(x, aes(displ, cty)) +
        geom_point() +
        # Fix limits
        scale_y_continuous(limits = range(mpg$cty))
      
      p + facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl), drop = FALSE) + 
        remove_labs_y +
        remove_axis_x
    }
  ) |> 
  wrap_plots(ncol = 1)
```

[image]